# Explicit solutions to simple one-dimensional fluid flow problems?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow

In order to test and verify numerical simulation results, I'm looking for explicit (or approximate) solutions to simple fluid flow problems to recalculate (like e.g. the pressure development during 1-dimensional flow through a planar crack etc.).

However, I've found it quite hard to find solutions like that online, because the sources mostly either refer to really old (pre-pdf) publications or expensive textbooks.

Does anybody know a good online source, that might be able to help me? Any links or other suggestions?

Edit:
I'm looking for solutions in a Eulerian frame of reference, since that would be the easiest to compare with simulation results where I would typically get the pressure as a function of time at distinct coordinates.

Comment: Lagrangian or Eulerian flows?

Comment: Related:http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60476/21144