# Finding the appropriate source term for 2D Pressure Driven Flow in a Square Channel

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm trying to solve the equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 v_z(x,y)}{\partial x^2} +
\frac{\partial^2 v_z(x,y)}{\partial y^2} =
\frac{\Delta P}{\mu \Delta X}
$$

This flow is supposed to be flowing in a  square channel (laminar,steady,fully developed).

I know I need to solve it numerically and if there was no source term I could just take the average of all four points around each node and get my answer. The problem is that I need to find the appropriate source term and I honestly don't know how to start. I also know I need to make the equation dimensionless. I know the source term can't be found analytically and I honestly am lost there. Can someone explain what the source term is and how I can start my quest to find it?

Comment: What do you think the terms are in the equation you're trying to solve? Isn't one of those the source term?

Comment: I did not do the calculation, but I think this question and the answer by Ron Maimon may help you: 

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31260/is-there-an-analytical-solution-for-fluid-flow-in-a-square-duct

Comment: Why do you want to solve it numerically? An analytical solution (in terms of an infinite series, but you can easily cut it off) exists for it. Check out the [Shah and London, 1978](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL4745920M/Laminar_flow_forced_convection_in_ducts)